# Conditional Volatility of GARCH squared residuals

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, arima, garch, volatility-forecasting

**Motivation**

I want to wrap up my own GARCH implementation

- to make sure I have understood the underlying model/assumption.
- to leverage `forecast::auto.arima` to automate model order selection (see below).
- to mitigate the potential issues with parameters, so that I don't have to switch to IGARCH when the sum of parameters are close to 1, etc.

**Background**

Suppose $a_t$ is a residual term with zero mean and zero conditional mean, the GARCH(p, q) model is given by

$$
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a_t &= \sigma_t \epsilon_t \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i a_{t-i}^2 + \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j \sigma_{t-j}^2
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
$$

Where $\epsilon_t \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \text{WN}(0, 1)$. If we let $\eta_t^2 := a_t^2 - \sigma_t^2$, then an alternative representation is

$$
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a_t &= \sigma_t \epsilon_t \\
a_t^2 &= \alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{\max(p, q)} (\alpha_i + \beta_i)a_{t-i}^2 + \eta_t - \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j \eta_{t-j}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
$$

According to my professor, $\eta_t$ can be proved to have zero mean, and are uncorrelated (but not independent).

**Methodology**

From above we can see that the squared residual $a_t^2$ is an ARMA process, so [as stated before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409712/whats-the-point-of-garch-when-you-can-square-the-residual-and-use-arma), I'll just fit an ARMA on $a_t^2$. As far as I know, we don't have `xxx::auto.garch` but there is `forecast::auto.arima`, which would help us to find the correct order of ARMA.

This lets us model/forecast the conditional mean of squared residuals. However, what we really care about is the conditional volatility of $a_t$, but I'm lost here.

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E(a_t^2 | I_{t-1}) &= \text{var}(a_t | I_{t-1}) \\
&= \text{var}(\sigma_t \epsilon_t | I_{t-1}) \\
&= \text{var}(\sigma_t | I_{t-1}) \text{var}(\epsilon_t | I_{t-1}) + \text{var}(\sigma_t | I_{t-1}) E^2(\epsilon_t | I_{t-1}) + \text{var}(\epsilon_t | I_{t-1}) E^2(\sigma_t | I_{t-1}) \\
&= \text{var}(\sigma_t | I_{t-1}) + E^2(\sigma_t | I_{t-1}) \\
&= \text{???}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

**Question**

How do I get "conditional volatility of residuals" from "conditional mean of squared residuals"?

Comment: Very interesting question! I had been wondering for a while whether `auto.arima` could be used for GARCH model selection much along the same lines as you did, but never had the time to work on that. If the solution is free from fatal conceptual mistakes, you could probably release a version of `auto.garch` for R users, it might become popular :)

Comment: @RichardHardy I love this idea. Will attempt it!

Answer (score 2):

I just add this piece to the reasoning to complement what you have said and asked, as it seems that your initial objective is to use the ARMA autofit to implement a GARCH autofit. In order to do this, you need to model the process for squared returns, which is not easy due to the fact that the distribution of the squared returns depends on the true distribution of returns. If you assume that the latter is normal, as it usual under normal QMLE, the the distribution of the squared returns is parametric as highlighted later. Now let’s highlight an additional source of complexity: an additional reason why it is not easy to implement a GARCH autofit, and is not correct to use the ARMA autofit, is that the innovations in squared returns cannot be assumed to be iid, as they are not independent. Therefore it is not theoretically possible to transform the specification of a GARCH into the specification of an ARMA on squared returns due to the latter problem. Anyway, if you wish to do so by forcing an iid assumptions on the innovations of squared return to simplify the derivation of the likelihood function, then consider that you need the conditional variance of squared returns. So read the following.

If you assume returns to be conditionally normal, then the conditional variance of squared returns is the variance of a squared normal distribution (as, if returns are conditionally normally distributed, here you are interested in the second central moment of the conditional distribution of their square). The formula for the calculation of the conditional variance of a squared normal with a given variance (which in your case is the given GARCH conditional variance, or the expected value of your squared ret) is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620045/mean-and-variance-of-squared-gaussian-y-x2-where-x-sim-mathcaln0-sigma) along with more complete info on the shape of the conditional distribution of the squared returns. You will need to assume that the fourth central moment of return distribution exists finite, which is ok.

Now you have the conditional mean of squared returns, which is the GARCH conditional variance, the conditional variance of squared returns, and the pdf (from the link provided). Now you can write the likelihood for an ARMA on squared returns. But you can do iff you force the assumptions that the innovations for squared returns are iid. Which we cannot say it is right. So pay attention to the problem that your QMLE estimator may have.

Comment: I think $\text{WN}(0,1)$ means white noise which is not necessarily $N(0,1)$. In finance, standardized innovations are often better described by distributions other than normal, e.g. Student-$t$. Even if standardized innnovations could be assumed to be normally distributed without too much trouble, one would not assume returns themselves to be conditionally normally distributed as they have considerably heavier tails. In any case, I am now wondering what is your concrete answer (complete the formula) and whether it is different from mine. If so, why the difference and what to do about it?

Comment: Hi Richard, I will be with you in a few hours! Thanks for the reminder. Essentially I anticipate you are right, indeed, I did not want to overcome your solution, just to integrate what already said highlighting that for a full-scale auto.spec you have to take into account the assumed conditional distribution of the squared returns, which may be not very simple in some cases

Comment: " I think WN(0,1) means white noise which is not necessarily N(0,1). In finance, standardized innovations are often better described by distributions other than normal, e.g. Student-t " yes, of course not even a Student-t: student t gives a better proxy with fat tails, but it is not even the correct solution for a good fit to most daily or intraday returns)..

Comment: I just exemplified with the normal, after a very quick look at the question (however you are right he just wrote WN, not NWN or N!). The point here is that when you want to work with an auto.fit you want to check what likelihood is the highest depending on the value of the parameters of your different models, which means that you have to work on the likelihood, which means that you have to assume a distribution for the innovations of squared returns (which moreover cannot be assumed to be fully iid!).

Comment: Even assuming they are iid, you have to take a parametric distribution, which as I tried to underline, depends on the assumed distribution of the return innovations. So as you see it is difficult to draw an autofit on a garch and ausing the auto.arma is not a trivial solution. This is to be underlined on my side. A solution is to say "Ok, I will use QMLE so that i can ignore the true distribution of innovations for the squared returns, at the cost of a decreased efficiency of the estimator), and assume another convenient distribution (exactly like you can use normal QMLE on ...

Comment: the distribution of innovations for returns, clearly here the two things are closely related). But again you have the problem of not iid innovations when it comes to the squared returns innovations. So this is why it gets difficult to use a auto.arma on squared returns to get to a auto.garch in my opinion.

Comment: OK, that is not really the question I was asking. I am wondering how you answer the question of the OP, *How do I get "conditional volatility of residuals" from "conditional mean of squared residuals"?*, and whether our answers differ. And if they differ, which one is right?

Comment: I see that in your answer you show that the conditional expected value of squared returns is the conditional variance. Am I correct? This is absolutely fine. But I read the initial question as “what is the conditional variance of the squared returns?” Which needs the kurthosis in the answer. Also because of the title and his intention of using the auto.arima on the squared return.. but maybe I just misinterpreted the initial question.. maybe I read it too quickly..

Comment: At least it seems that his intention was that.. then he wrote the =??? That you completed well.. but as I told you initially, since it seems that his intention was that one, I decided to add a piece.. if you wish I just ask to cancel my answer, that is not to the =??? It is more the answer to How I get to the conditional volatility of SQUARED RESIDUALS from the conditional mean of SQURED RESIDUALS, which is what he needs to complete a home-brewing garch.autofit provided that you force the iid assumption on the innovations for the model of squared returns..

Comment: This is the root of the misunderstanding on the answers.. they are likely to be the answers for two distinct questions implicitly embedded into the initial complicated question that jumps from a problem to another and in the last statement denoted as “Question:” asks something very very trivial that is not very logically connected with the initial problem of finding a garch.autofit, so probably a better question would have been “how can I get to variance of squared returns.. etc”

Comment: Probably he got a bit confused as indeed he wrote “I am lost here..” indeed it seems like he was. Because the initial aim of finding a auto.garch is maybe too ambitious. Which is why I completed (not replaced!) the answers saying “ok pay attention to the fact that, in order to do what you really want to do, then you need to consider this, and assume this etc..”

Comment: @RichardHardy I edited my answer, so now the aim of my initial answer should be better understandable

Comment: I see, thank you for your explication! It makes sense. I am in favor of indicating clearly how the answer is related to the question, which you have now done. I am still wondering if the variance derivation in your given link is relevant to the specific question in the context you are mentioning it (GARCH conditional variance). The answer it gives is different from mine (which is a direct answer), since the question it is answering is a different one (than the direct question).

Comment: @RichardHardy I had some troubles understanding the real question as I hinted before, because on one hand you think “so a guy that is trying to make an autofit on garch is really having troubles understanding that the Garch indicates the conditional expectation for the squared returns?” So I interpreted the situation like “ok he is trying to find the variance of the variance, which is not a trivial question”.. especially because when he asks How do I get the conditional volatility of residuals from the conditional mean of squared returns” seems like he was referring to the..

Comment: Seems like he was referring to the residuals for the process of squared returns, that he cited a line before. which made sense because that was the interesting question. Indeed he also adds from the conditional mean of squared returns” so I thought he already had the right view that the Garch indicates the conditional expectation for squared returns. Anyway Richard, I apologize for the inconvenience, as l esteem your contributions here. As you may have noticed it is not my use to write an answer where an answer has already been provided, here I’m i intention was to add something ...

Comment: .. something useful on the whole context of the question. That, as I said multiple times, was a question with multiple facets, multiple points, not 100% clear, punctual or direct in my opinion, so there was room to add some details on a topic like Garch specification, that is something not so often discussed here, but very important and not very trivial under many points of view. And, most importantly, I apologize for getting back to you just now. The problem is that I am terribly busy in this period. Terribly does not give the right idea.. I would say horribly..

Comment: Tomorrow I will likely get back to you on the other question (my question, where you have commented), and I will add my answer that has been pending for some days.

Comment: No need to apologize, really. Thank you for being so considerate!

Answer (score 1):

Given that $\sigma_t^2$ is part of $I_{t-1}$ because of
$$
\sigma_t^2 = \alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i a_{t-i}^2 + \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j \sigma^2_{t-j}
$$
and given
$$
\epsilon_t \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \text{WN}(0, 1),
$$
couldn't you do
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E(a_t^2 | I_{t-1}) &= \text{var}(a_t | I_{t-1}) \\
&= \text{var}(\sigma_t \epsilon_t | I_{t-1}) \\
&= \sigma_t^2 \text{var}(\epsilon_t | I_{t-1}) \\
&= \sigma_t^2 \cdot 1 \\
&=\alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i a_{t-i}^2 + \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j \sigma^2_{t-j}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
?

Comment: BTW, is "conditional volatility of residuals" just "conditional mean of squared residuals"? We have $E(a_t^2 | I_{t-1}) = \text{var}(a_t | I_{t-1})$, but your [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410792/108877) to my previous question suggests there are some subtle differences.

Comment: @nalzok, if residuals $a_t$ are guaranteed to have a conditional mean of zero, then by definition of the conditional variance $\text{Var}(a_t|I_{t-1})=\mathbb{E}(a_t^2|I_{t-1})-(\mathbb{E}(a_t|I_{t-1}))^2=\mathbb{E}(a_t^2|I_{t-1})-0^2=\mathbb{E}(a_t^2|I_{t-1})$.

Comment: I see, but I still can't wrap my head around it. What are we interested in when using GARCH, $\text{var}(a_t|I_{t-1})$ or $E(\sigma_t^2|I_{t-1})$? In your previous answer, you referred to $\sigma_t^2$ as "the conditional variance", but a random variable can't be conditional by itself, so I'm kinda confused.

Comment: @nalzok, not sure exactly what question we have here, but I will try. Since $\sigma^2_t|I_{t-1}$ is a constant (not a random variable), $\mathbb{E}(\sigma^2_t|I_{t-1})=\sigma^2_t=\alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i a_{t-i}^2 + \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j \sigma^2_{t-j}$. The random variable of interest is $a_t$ the conditional variance of which is $\sigma^2_t$. According to GARCH, the moments of $a_t$ are determined by the past values of $a_t$, so the random variable is producing the parameters of its own future. This is common to all autoregressive models.

Comment: Your explanation is quite clear, thanks!

Comment: Hi: This idea is interesting but note that it's not going to be that straightforward to use an ARIMA algorithm because you've got a constraint since the coefficient, $\beta_{j}$ is present in both terms of the ARMA. I don't have much experience with GARCH  but this may  be one of the reasons why it is notoriously difficult to fit GARCH processes.

Comment: @mlofton, thanks, got it.